# Create an array populated with a range of values x through y

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Let's say I have integer variables x and y, and I want an array populated with values x through y.  Is there a nice way to do this inline, using C#?

I know I can achieve this using an extension method:

```
public static int[] ExpandToArray(this int x, int y)
{
    var arr = int[y - x + 1];
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) 
    {
        arr[i-x] = i;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And then use it to write:

```
x.ExpandToArray(y);
```

Is there a built-in way (without creating an extension method) in .NET to write something like `x.ExpandToArray(y)`?

Comment: Why use a list when the number of items is fixed and known?

Comment: @harold although after rewriting it, looking at the jumble of variables gives me a headache.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(x, y - x + 1).ToArray();
```

Parameter #1 is start value.
Parameter #2 is count.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks.  I felt certain something like this had to exist.

Comment: If param 2 is count, then shouldn't it be `y - x + 1`. If you wanted values from 4 to 4, then count should be 1, not zero.